Kubernetes ingress resource path does not get passed correctly to service
I have the following Ingress resource:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: user-management-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: react-frontend
            port:
              number: 80
      - path: /api/user-management/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: user-management
            port:
              number: 80

The react frontend works fine. On visit the files under /assets/ can be loaded without problems
My user-management service does not get passed the rest of the path. Only the root get's triggered.
If I try to visit /api/user-management/test which should trigger user-management/test endpoint it still responds with the the user-management/ root endpoint. It does not matter what I add to the path behind it.
How can I solve this?
I tried variations on the PathType and matchingGroups with regex but to no success

Change your annotation as that configures the path rewriting
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /user-management/$1

